# Product of two Polynomials python

Tags: python

I wrote this polynomial class, but I'm having a problem getting the **mul** over loader to return the correct result. It work for the highest and lowest degrees of the polynomial, but it returns an incorrect coefficient for the inside degrees. I think it has to do with the way I'm updating the values of the coefficient. Please help.

```
class Polynomial:
def __init__(self, *termpairs):
    termdict1={}
    for i in termpairs:
        termdict1[i[1]]=i[0]      
    self.termdict = termdict1
def __str__(self):
    k = sorted(self.termdict, reverse = True)
    v = 0
    x = ''
    for i in k:
        if i == 0:  
                x += str(self.termdict.get(i))
        elif i == 1:
            if self.termdict.get(i) > 0:
                x+=' + '
                x+=str(self.termdict.get(i))
                x+='x'
            else:
                x+= ' - '
                x+=str(abs(self.termdict.get(i)))
                x+='x'
        elif i > 1:
            if self.termdict.get(i) > 0:
                x+=' + '
                x+=str(self.termdict.get(i))
                x+='x^'
                x+=str(i)
            else:
                x+=' - '
                x+=str(abs(self.termdict.get(i)))
                x+='x^'
                x+=str(i)
        elif i < 0:
            x+=' - '
            x+=str(abs(self.termdict.get(i)))
            x+='x^'
            x+=str(i)
    if x[1] == '+':
        return(x[3:])
    else:
        return(x) 

def degree(self):
    k = sorted(self.termdict, reverse = True)
    return(k[0])
def evaluate(self,x):
    final = 0
    for k,v in self.termdict.items():
        print(k,v)
        final += v*(x**k)
    return(final)
def addterm(self,x,y):
    if y in self.termdict.keys():
        self.termdict[y] = (self.termdict.get(y) + x)
    else:
        self.termdict[y] = x
    return(self.termdict)
def removeterm(self,x):
    if x in self.termdict.keys():
        del self.termdict[x]
    return(self.termdict)
def scale(self,x):
    for k in self.termdict.keys():
        self.termdict[k] = (self.termdict.get(k) * x)  
    return(self.termdict)
def __add__(self,other):
    New = Polynomial()
    for k,v in self.termdict.items():
        New.addterm(v,k)
    for k,v in other.termdict.items():
        New.addterm(v,k)
def __sub__(self,other):
    s = Polynomial()
    x = Polynomial()
    for k,v in self.termdict.items():
        s.addterm(v,k)
    print(s.termdict)
    for key in other.termdict.keys():
        s.removeterm(key)
    for k,v in other.termdict.items():
        x.addterm(v,k)
    print(x.termdict)
    for key in self.termdict.keys():
        x.removeterm(key)
    for k,v in x.termdict.items():
        s.addterm(-1*v,k)
    print(s.termdict)  
    return(s.termdict)
def __mul__(self,other):
    S = Polynomial()
    for k,v in other.termdict.items():
        for key, value in self.termdict.items():  
                S.termdict[key+k]=(value*v)
    print(S)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple term pairs could mulitply to give the same power in the result - eg, $x^2 * x$ and $x * x^2$ both give $x^3$. These coefficients need to be added, while you're effectively ignoring all but the last one you find. So the update in the second last line needs to be:

```
S.termdict[key+k] = S.termdict.get(key+k, 0) + value*v
```

You can make this quite a bit nicer if you initialise termdict1 in `__init__` as a `defaultdict(int)` (from the collections module) - the above would become:

```
S.termdict[key + k] += value*v
```